# Sending data with angular router

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a search-box where you search from an array full of TV shows (and their corresponding ID's).

**landingpage.component.html**

```
 <li (click)="selectShow(list.show)" [routerLink]="['/details', list.id]" *ngFor="let list of shows"> </li>
```

When a user clicks a show, it passes on the id of that show to a new route as a parameter, and loads my **resultpage.component**. The selectShow function just logs the name of the selected show.

**My problem:**

I want to send the show (*list.show*) value to my **resultpage.component**, via the Angular router. I can't seem to find any information on how to do this in the docs.

How can I pass my *list.show* data to my resultpage.component using the Angular router?

Comment: If you want data to be shared between different components then services is what you should try. Not sure how to do that using router but yes can do using services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the route will not have anything more than the `list.id` you need to fetch the data when you visit the `/details` link.

This is usually done by creating a `Resolve` for the data

https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

What that does is before you visit your `/details` it checks to see if you have registered any resolvers for that route.

You will then be able to get that data from the router.

```
@Component()
export class DetailComponent implements OnInit {

  listDetails: Details;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.listDetails = this.route.snapshot.data['details'];
  }
}
```